# How to make blender confirm closing an unsaved file?

Tags: blender

If I modify a file in blender, then close blender, it deletes my changes, without warning.

How can I make blender check before closing unsaved changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to 2.80, at least when it comes out. Yes this has finally been added to the next major release due out later this year.

Unfortunately this is the way blender has always worked, it wants you to be sure you want to save your data and will throw it out without a second thought. The current versions have some limited modification checking for [windows](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/interface.html#warnings) but not other platforms.

Blender does have some autosave features that can help [recover data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/recover.html) in some situations, so if you think of it right away, you can access a save that was done before blenders previous quit, if you open and close blender again before thinking of it, it will be gone, but you could have other autosave copies available until you restart your machine. You can [change the autosave location](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5224/935) so that these are available for longer.

Comment: sorry it took a while for me to accept this answer--I still really appreciate it.

Comment: 2.79 from development builds also have this function, 2.80 is alpha and unstable at current time